# Howto optimize webpack chunking with vue.config.js to speed up gitlab build time

Tags: vue.js, webpack, gitlab-ci, chunking

My original configuration in vue.config.js using the default chunking strategy, which takes about 5 minutes to build locally and 35 minutes in gitlab pipeline, and results in one chunk being > 50MB and several other large chunks(see screenshot)

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  },
  publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_PATH || '/',
  configureWebpack: {
  },
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: "src/main.js",
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "index"]
    },


      visualform: {
        entry: "src/visualform/main.js",
        template: "public/visualform.html",
        filename: "visualform.html",
        chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "visualform"],
      }
  }
};
```

[image: output of building locally]

So after having a read of the webpack docs i thought i'd use the following updated config to try and reduce the chunk size

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  },
  publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_PATH || '/',
  configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.AggressiveSplittingPlugin({
                minSize: 20000,
                maxSize: 200000,
            }),
        ],
  },
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: "src/main.js",
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "index"]
    },


      visualform: {
        entry: "src/visualform/main.js",
        template: "public/visualform.html",
        filename: "visualform.html",
        chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "visualform"],
      }
  }
};
```

which results in the following reduced chunk size, but appears to break the app(there is no more index.js and visualform.js present, i also tried having an output section in configureWebpack with filename, but made no difference)

[image: output of building locally with updated chunking]

When i access the app through the browser i get a blank page and the following in console

[image: console output]

A bunch of messages like this:

**The resource http://localhost:3000/js/379.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.**

I've also tried doing  a split chunk optimization in configure webpack to try and overide the default chunking of vue cli service:

```
configureWebpack: {
optimization: {
splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                       chunks: 'all',
                      minSize: 20000,
                      maxSize: 200000,
                      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
                    'chunk-vendors': {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                         name(module) {
        
                           const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
                          
                           return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                         },
                      chunks: 'all',
                      priority: -10,
                      maxAsyncRequests: 6,
                      maxInitialRequests: 4,
                      minChunks: 2,
                      minSize: 20000,
                      maxSize: 200000,
                      reuseExistingChunk: true,
                      enforce: true
                    },
                     'chunk-common': {
                       name: 'chunk-common',
                       test: path.resolve('src/components'), 
                       chunks: 'all',
                       minChunks: 3, //  minimum common number
                       minSize: 20000,
                       maxSize: 250000,
                       priority: 5,
                       reuseExistingChunk: true,
                     }
               }
            }
    }
}
```

But this strategy results in the same blank page, no entry point visualform.js and main.js pages being generated, and associated warnings in console

[image]

**The resource http://localhost:3000/js/npm.element-ui~._node_modules_element-ui_lib_t.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.**

Any help would be much appreciated. The chunking reduces the build time in gitlab pipeline by about 65%, so if i can get it working will minimize this bottleneck.

I'm a bit of a webpack noob and have been reading the docs, but there are a lot of config options, so i've probably missed something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Identified which component was the largest chunk and applied dynamic loading to the imported components within as per the docs here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html

This reduced my build time in gitlab pipeline to around 9 minutes